# Music not playing when app is in the background Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've written this code to play music while my app runs but when I go to another app the music stops.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    playBackgroundMusic("anti.mp3")


}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

import AVFoundation

var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    guard let newURL = url else {
        print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }
    do {
        backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

I also added the audio string in the info.plist under required background modes.

I get this output as well, so I thought it would continue playing in the background while using other apps but it does not.

```
AVAudioSession Category Playback OK
AVAudioSession is Active
AVAudioSession Category Playback OK
AVAudioSession is Active
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `Audio,Airplay and picture in picture` is checked in `background modes` under `capabilities` under `target` under `project setup`

Check the screenshot

[image]